# How to change the color of different files in ls

Tags: bash, shell, ls

So I know that there is a way to change the color of text for directories, regular files, bash scripts, etc. Is there a way to change the color to the file based on the `_file extension_`?

Example:

```
$ ls -l
foo.txt  [is red] 
foo.text  [is blue] 
foo.secret  [is green] 
foo.txt  [is red]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, using the `LS_COLORS` variable (assuming GNU `ls`). The easiest way to manipulate that is to use `dircolors`:

```
dircolors --print-database > dircolors.txt
```

will dump the current settings to `dircolors.txt`, which you can then edit; once you've added your settings,

```
eval $(dircolors dircolors.txt)
```

will update `LS_COLORS` and export it. You should add that to your shell startup script.

To apply the example settings you give, the entries to add to `dircolors.txt` would be

```
.txt 00;31
.text 00;34
.secret 00;32
```

Comment: Thanks man. btw, could this work? `.tar.gz 01;31` and `.zip.gz 02;31` work?

Comment: It's easy enough to try for yourself ;-). But yes, it will work, although `02` doesn't match anything so `02;31` is equivalent to `00;31` (standard red).

Comment: in many terminal emulators, `02` is used to dim the color

Comment: So it does, thanks @cheesits456!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this (not the best way) is to make a custom shell function:

```
myls() {
  for f in *; do
    if [ "${f##*.}" = txt ]; then
      printf '\e[1;31m%s\e[0m\n' "$f"
    elif [ "${f##*.}" = text ]; then
      printf '\e[1;34m%s\e[0m\n' "$f"
    elif [ "${f##*.}" = secret ]; then
      printf '\e[1;32m%s\e[0m\n' "$f"
    else
      printf '%s\n' "$f"
    fi
  done
}
```

Further reading:

- ["Friendly" terminal color names in shell scripts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/92563/135943)