# How to changes colors for files that their group owner is `root`?

Tags: shell, ls, colors

I have tried [How to change the color of different files in ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/322032/198423)'s solution to apply color changes in `ls`. I have observed that they do not apply in folders that has a  `root` group owner?

For example a `.json` file differs in color in a root folder and a user's home folder.

[image]

---

```
~/folder/ > ls -l
-rw-rw-r-- 1 alper alper alper 0 2021-06-16 06:35 hello.json

~/mnt/ > ls -l
-rwxrwxrwx 1 alper root alper 0 2021-06-16 06:38 alper.json
```

Related question: https://superuser.com/q/1598934/723632, which has a solution only for folders.

Comment: isn't it related to access ? e.g. what is the result of `ls -l` one of those file must be x (executable) and the other not.

Comment: I had no idea `json` files could be executable.  Please see my updated question for `ls -l` results.

Comment: @alper any file can be executable. it depends solely on file permission, not on a file name or extension.

Comment: I have tried `chmod -x alper.json` to remove the executable bit but still its color remain unchanged @rush

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think GNU `ls` can color conditionally based on the group owner.

However, you can use a filter program like [GRC](https://github.com/garabik/grc) (Generic Colouriser). GRC further colors commands' output, including making root user/group ownership red:

[image: screenshot of GRC with a directory listing]

So on Debian/Ubuntu, that's `sudo apt install grc` and then `alias ls='grc -es ls -ph --color=auto'`, then you can run `ls -l` or `ll` (assuming `alias ll='ls -l'`).

Comment: You might have any idea why color for `root` inside the red box is kind of light whith rather than complete white. I think being bold affects its color

Comment: Also in some cases `ls` prints multiple filenames in single line but `grc` seems like it prints only line by line

Comment: Bold is often rendered as a lighter color rather than actually bold. That depends on your terminal emulator, which you can probably configure. The screenshot I shared is from xfce4-terminal. You could alternatively edit the `ls.conf` file from /usr/share/grc/ (copy it to `~/.grc/`).

Comment: I don't think `grc` is helpful for `ls` without `-l` (long). For one, `ls` knows it's being piped and resorts to `-1` (one file per line), so you'd need to run it through `column -t` or something like it, but again `grc` doesn't do anything useful here.