# Output in color - Bash

Tags: bash, terminal, colors

I have seen several answers but they all talk about `echo`. How can I change the color of an output of a command in bash?
For instance, I want to colorize the output of `hostname` command.

```
$ hostname 
Nameofcomputer <--- Just the output to be colored and then it returns to default color of the shell.
```

Comment: How will your system decide what and how to colour? i.e. do you want to hard code specific colours into specific commands? e.g. `hostname` should always output red?

Comment: FWIW I don't think it's a dupe, but it's certainly unclear IMO.

Comment: @Sparhawk for example $ set-color red hostname , just want the outout of command to be in certain color and then the prompt returns to default color

Comment: I would try writing functions that echo'd out the color-changing sequences, then ran `command the-original-command "$@"`, then the end-color sequence. You might be able to make a set-color function that creates such functions on-demand as well. Beware commands (such as some greps) that may declare their own colors.

Comment: I wrote up a partial answer, just as @JeffSchaller posted. It's basically the same strategy, but fails in some cases.

Answer (score 4):

This code seems to work, thank to suggestions from @finefoot.

```
#!/bin/bash

case $1 in
  red)     col=$'\e[1;31m' ;;
  green)   col=$'\e[1;32m' ;;
  yellow)  col=$'\e[1;33m' ;;
  blue)    col=$'\e[1;34m' ;;
  magenta) col=$'\e[1;35m' ;;
  cyan)    col=$'\e[1;36m' ;;
esac

printf "%s" "${col}"

shift
exec "$@"
```

### Usage

Presuming it's called `set-color`, simply call it with `set-color red hostname`.

### Explanation

- The case block defines the colours, as per jasonwryan's answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/92568/18887).
- The script sets this colour with `printf`.
- `shift` removes the first option fed to the script (i.e. the colour).
- `exec "$@"` then executes the rest of the script.

Comment: @finefoot Sparhawk replied (in a now-deleted) comment that quoting didn't help. One difference I see in your pastebin code is `exec` vs `eval` so that would need to be considered.

Comment: @finefoot It's been half a decade since I posted this, and I don't use bash any more, but I tested your changes and they seem to work. Thank you and edited! (FWIW on my system `$'...'` is fine with `#!/bin/sh`, but quoting `$@` didn't work.)

Comment: @Sparhawk Maybe your `sh` just links to `bash` and that's why it works? No idea... "`$'...'` is a bashism" (quote from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh) so it shouldn't work with a strictly POSIX shell I guess? Never mind. :) Again, very helpful post! Thanks for keeping it updated.

Comment: @finefoot It *does* link to `bash`, but when run as `sh`, `bash` goes into POSIX mode. There are certainly some differences on my system though. Re-reading my previous comment I was not clear, but I meant to say that I did need `#!/bin/bash` for the quoting of "$@" to work. This didn't work with `sh`.

Answer (score 3):

There are programs that will already do this for you, like `grc`, it's a

> generic colouriser, can be used to colourise logfiles,
>   output of commands, arbitrary text....
>   configured via regexp's.

[image]

<sub>[I normally don't like to use an image of text, but I don't think StackExchange has colour fomrat options]</sub>

Or there's also [`source-highlight`](http://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/).

See [Is there colorizer utility that can take command output and colorize it accordingly to pre-defined scheme?](https://superuser.com/questions/602294/is-there-colorizer-utility-that-can-take-command-output-and-colorize-it-accordin) on SuperUser too

Answer (score 2):

```
tput setaf 1; hostname; tput sgr0
```

`tput` queries the terminal database for the corresponding capability. Here `setaf` for *set ANSI colour 1* (red), `sgr0` to *select graphic rendition none* to go back to default attributes. Instead of `tput sgr0`, you can also use `tput op` (original pair) to only reset background and foreground colour and leave other graphic attributes (bold, underline, standout, reverse...) alone.

Some shells like `zsh`, `tcsh` or `fish` have builtin support to query that database or map color names to ANSI codes (like `zsh` or [`fish`](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#set_color)), but not `bash`.

In `zsh`, using prompt expansion to print the hostname in `red`:

```
print -P '%F{red}%m%f'
```

(`%f` only resets the foreground colour)

In `tcsh` or `zsh` with the `echotc` builtin using termcap codes instead of terminfo:

```
echotc AF 1; hostname; echotc me
```

(`zsh` has `echoti` for the terminfo codes setab/sgr0 like modern versions of `tput`).

In `zsh`, the `%` parameter expansion flag turns on prompt expansion upon parameter expansion, so you can do:

```
red=%F{red} normal=%f

echo ${(%)red}whatever%{(%)normal}
```

In `zsh`, you'll also find a `colors` autoloadable function that you can run to have helpers to write things in colour:

```
autoload colors; colors

echo $fg[red]whatever$fg[default]
```