# How to edit $PS1 variable so that the output of a bash command is another color than the command?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, colors

How to edit `$PS1` variable so that the output of a bash command is another color than the command? For example, I want the command to be black, and the output to be green.

```
username$ seq 1 3
1
2
3
```

In the above example, I would want `seq 1 3` to be black, and the output numbers to be green.

This is my current $PS1 variable:

```
\[\e[1;0:31m\]\u \[\e[m\] \[\e[1;0:36m\] \@ \[\e[m\] \[\e[1;0:32m\]\W $ \[\e[m\]
```

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363143/output-in-color-bash

Answer (score 2):

You should make use of `trap "changesColorHere"  DEBUG` and `PS1`. In the `PS1` variable you can specify at the end of its value the color and what `trap "" DEBUG` does is to run a command immediately before another is executed. So, if you run `df` the command specified in `trap "" DEBUG` will before `df`.

You can set `PS1` variable to this:

```bash
PS1="\[\e[1;0:31m\]\u \[\e[m\] \[\e[1;0:36m\] \@ \[\e[m\] \[\e[1;0:32m\]\W $ \[\e[1;35m\]"
```

With this setting all input you type after the prompt will be colored.

And you can set `trap ""  DEBUG` to something like this:

```bash
trap "echo -ne '\e[1;33m'"  DEBUG
```

With this setting the output of **almost** every command you type will be colored.

Some commands such `ls`,`dmesg`,`journcaltcl`, etc will show the output with the colors they are configured. So you have to disable them by using:

1. When you use `ls` this command is usually an alias which has the option `--color=tty`. So to be able to print the ls output with your custom color you can use:

```bash
\ls #Add `\` before the ls command
ls --color=never ... # Add the option --color=never
```

2. The `dmesg` command prints the output with its custom colors but you can prevent to use them and use the yours instead:

```bash
dmesg --color=never #Add --color=never
```

3. `journalctl` also prints its output with custom colors. Although this can be disabled by exporting `export SYSTEMD_COLORS=false` if you simply use `journalctl` the output will make use of the `less` command. So I suggest you use:

```bash
export SYSTEMD_COLORS=false
journalctl  --no-pager
#Alternatively you can use:
journalctl | cat #This should be useful if there were commands whose page their
# output through `less` and they do not have an option like `--no-pager`
```

---

Using the settings above I have:

[image]