# Prevent tput escape sequences when redirecting script output to a file

Tags: terminal, io-redirection, colors, xterm, tput

I have a shell function that colorizes a filename using `tput`.

```
color=$( tput setaf 1 )
normal=$( tput sgr0 )
colorize() {
    echo "${color}$1$(normal)"
}
```

When I call the function, the terminal displays the colorized filename as expected.

```
$ myScript.sh .
/path/to/dir # (in color red)
```

Then, if I redirect output to a file:

```
$ myScript.sh > /tmp/file.log
```

`file.log` still contains escapes sequences like:

```
^[[36m~/path/to/my/file/^[(B^[[[m
```

Could this be related to the **TERM** and **infocomp**, and how terminal interprets escape sequences?

The idea is to simulate a "non-display" terminal, isn't it?

My TERM is (Ubuntu 16.04):

```
$ echo $TERM
xterm
```

**What should I do to prevent such `tput` escape sequences when my script is redirected to a file?**

Workaround: add an option to my script to disable colorization manually, as in `ls` or `grep` like `--color=none`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

short: tput doesn't do that.

longer: your script can do that

For example, check if the standard output is a terminal:

```
if [ -t 1 ]
then
    color=$( tput setaf 1 )
    normal=$( tput sgr0 )
else
    color=""
    normal=""
fi
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm, and this even does not need to rewrite the echo command as you empty the color variables when not for a terminal output. Nice!

Comment: I am facing a problem with this technique. I have 2 .sh scripts, both using the technique, and both echoing colored output.
The caller script successfully echoes colors, but the subscript does not, maybe because STDOUT is not redirected to a terminal but to a `echo` of my caller script. What to do to use this with subsripts ?

Comment: I solutionned the subscript problem by using: `[[ -t 1 ]] && export coloredModed=1` in caller script, and `if [[ -t 1 || $coloredMode = 1 ]]` in subscript